# Trying to set web browser control to display HTML markup in MFC application

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, webbrowser-control

I added a web browser control (IE) into my dialog based MFC project. Now I need to make it display my HTML markup from memory. That seems like a simple thing, but I can't make it to work. I keep finding code [like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#code-snippet-1) that sets it to a web page.

Upon further research, I saw people setting it from an override of the `DownloadComplete` event. So I first set my web page to display an empty page by using the [Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752134(v=vs.85).aspx) method and then tried to set it from `DownloadComplete` as such:

```
CString gm_SomeGlobalVar;

void CMyDialogDlg::SetWebBrowserCtrlWithHTML(CString* pHTML)
{
    gm_SomeGlobalVar = *pHTML;

    COleVariant varNull;
    COleVariant varUrl = urlForEmptyWebPage;

    m_browser.Navigate2(varUrl, varNull, varNull, varNull, varNull);
}


BEGIN_EVENTSINK_MAP(CMyDialogDlg, CDialog)
    ON_EVENT(CMyDialogDlg, IDC_EXPLORER1, 104, CMyDialogDlg::DownloadCompleteExplorer1, VTS_NONE)
END_EVENTSINK_MAP()

void CMyDialogDlg::DownloadCompleteExplorer1()
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    SetHTMLCtrlBody(&gm_SomeGlobalVar);
}

BOOL CMyDialogDlg::SetHTMLCtrlBody(CString* pStrHTML)
{
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    TRY
    {
        if(pStrHTML)
        {
            HRESULT hr;
            LPDISPATCH pDisp = m_browser.get_Document();
            if(pDisp != NULL)
            {
                CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pIDoc2;
                if(SUCCEEDED(hr = pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void**)&pIDoc2)))
                {
                    CComPtr<IHTMLElement> pBody;
                    if(SUCCEEDED(hr = pIDoc2->get_body(&pBody)))
                    {
                        //For some dumb reason 'pBody' can still be NULL here
                        if(pBody)
                        {
                            BSTR htmlBStr = pStrHTML->AllocSysString();
                            if(htmlBStr)
                            {
                                if(SUCCEEDED(hr = pBody->put_innerHTML(htmlBStr)))
                                {
                                    bRes = TRUE;
                                }

                                SysFreeString(htmlBStr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                pDisp->Release();
            }
        }
    }
    CATCH_ALL(e)
    {
        //Failed
        ASSERT(NULL);
        bRes = FALSE;
    }
    END_CATCH_ALL

    return bRes;
}
```

But this brings up more issues:

1. The `DownloadComplete` is somehow called twice.
2. I then tried to use [get_ReadyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415481.aspx) to see when the document state is reported as `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` but it never does. I receive it as `READYSTATE_LOADING` and `READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE`.
3. Plus it's a horribly inelegant solution, namely when my `SetWebBrowserCtrlWithHTML()` method returns, the HTML may not be set up yet.
4. Lastly, calling my `SetHTMLCtrlBody()` from `SetWebBrowserCtrlWithHTML()` right after `m_browser.Navigate2()` returns, results in `TRUE` but the HTML markup isn't shown in the web browser control.

So I was wondering, there must a better way of doing it?

Comment: Unless you're feeling completely masochistic, store your data to a file and have the browser display that file.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yes, it's one way. I just can't image that a control doesn't allow loading from memory.

Comment: Keep in mind that although it's *wrapped* as a control, it's still just a wrapper around IE.

Comment: Check drillerMFC sample from [Web Development Archives: WebBrowser and MSHTML](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=944).

Comment: You can put the content in a block of memory and use IPersistStreamInit.  It will work for the first time you load it.

Comment: @Noseratio: So what exactly do I need to look for in the DrillerMFC app? It uses Navigate2() method just like I showed above. Why did you link it?

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson: Thanks, that's really promising. Unfortunately I don't have much experience using `IPersistStreamInit`. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @c00000fd, my memory let me down, I thought DrillerMFC was dealing with `IPersistStreamInit`.

Comment: why not use CDHtmlDialog? Resource editor will do it for you. Or you can use CHtmlEditCtrl with edit-mode turn off.